# Creating Tables with Multiple Headers in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to create a table with multiple headers using `DataGridView` in C#. I can create a table. However, I need multiple headers in the table. Attached is the screenshot of the table I would like to create.

Any idea how to do it.

[image]

Comment: If you can post some code what you have tried, it will be easier to proceed because its not something you get out-of-the-box. Needs overriding of `Paint` and `Invalidated` handlers (of DataGridView) I guess.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not sure yet how to achieve it. I currently have a simple table with columns " Date, ClientName etc". I populate each row from the databse. I would like to have additional header to classify rows( and data) based on date

Comment: I am not sure you can do this in a formal way (type of pivot table). The only way I can suggest is to add the row `Yesterday` for instance with the other columns blank - although this does not seem satisfactory it may be the only way to go...

Comment: Have a look at this - _http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/two-row-headers-datagridview-t3708144.html_

Answer (score 1):

This is the concept regarding DataGrid with in DataGrid.You first have to Bind MasterGrid and then bind Child grids with in Master grid.This link will surely help you :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22928/GridView-within-GridView`